# How to see other participants in Outlook 2007 appointments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

When I receive an invitation for an appointment (sorry don't know if that the right Outlook-term, I only have the German version here) I see the list of participants.

Once I accept it, I no longer see who was/is invited.

When my accept message gets sent, I see in that sent folder message from that time who is in/out, etc. But it's not updated when other participants accept/deny the invitation.

Can this be enabled somewhere to see either the original list of persons who were invited *or* who who've accepted/denied the invitation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you just open the appointment up and click "Scheduling" (or rather the appropriate German equivalent name) on the ribbon. It should then show the current state of attendees, along with their free/busy info.

This is also useful when arranging a meeting, because you can see everyone's free/busy info to see when people are available and avoid clashes.

Comment: Awesome! I did knew that functionality for **creating** appointments but never tried to look at it after one was done or when I accepted one. Many thanks!